# WSO2 Identity Server 6.0 - Token generation issue for Secondary Userstore users

Tags: wso2, access-token, wso2-identity-server

This seems to be a peculiar issue. We have seen people having this problem in lower versions of WSO2 but I have accommodated all those suggestions.

We are currently using WSO2 IS v5.10 in PRD and want to upgrade to 6.0. However, when we are trying to do a POC with all the customizations we have and plan for a upgrade, we are stuck at token generation for secondary userstores. **Always getting invalid_grant 400 Bad Request error**

Just to brief on wat we have done so far -

- Installed WSO2 IS v6.0 using the zip in LINUX machine
- Changed the default database to MySQL instead of H2
- Have copied all the necessary dependent jars to the respective lib/dropins folders
- Have a customization jar added in /components/dropins folder in which we have our custom grant and custom user stores defined
- From the Management console, we can see our Custom User stores listed in the dropdown (one is Oracle and one is LDAP) which we are adding as Secondary User stores. We have multi-tenant model, so each tenant has one custom user store attached to it
- From the Managements Console, I can see List of Users, so basically connection works and doListUsers works as expected
- Have added a Service Provider and have enabled all the default grants under the OAuth/OpenID Connect Configurations including Password grant
  -Have some custom claims so have added them Claim Configurations of the Service Provider
- From Postman, when I try to hit the /oauth2/token endpoint with the Client ID and Client Secret we are **always getting invalid_grant 400 Bad Request error** (Authorization Type - Basic Auth with Client ID and Secret)
  [Postman Request Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNDyB.png)
- However, if we add a new Service Provider in the admin account pointing to the Primary Userstore, the token generation is successful
- The Custom user store extends AbstractUserStoreManager and have overridden methods like doAuthenticate, getUserPropertyValues, doCheckExistingUser, doListUsers etc
- After changing the log level of user.core to DEBUG and going through the logs - what we realize is that the token endpoint is actually invoking our custom class, doCheckExistingUser is called, user is found, but doAuthenticate is not getting invoked. It end up saying this in the logs
  **DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} - Authentication failure. Wrong username or password is provided.**

Can anyone help us on this. The same custom user store and the configurations just work fine in 5.10 and 5.11 as well but not in 6.0. Despite doing multiple checks on what's changed/expected in 6.0 we are no able to fix this invalid_grant issue - this is occurring on password and code grant types. Client_crendentials work fine.

Comment: Here when you say you have changed the database from H2 to MySQL have you used the same database you used in IS 5.10. Have you followed the migration document https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/deploy/migrate/migrate-to-600/

Comment: Also I can get that you have created a SP from admin account and it worked. But im not clear about the scenario that does not work what is that SP has different with the working SP

Comment: I have cretaed a new database and ran the mysql.sql files in the dbscripts folder. So its a fresh instance. The SP from admin account was just to confirm if token generation works on the primary store. The actual SP that we use are in the tenants cretaed to which we have secondary userstore attached.

Comment: Thank you very much  @BuddhimaUdaranga for your interest to help. What I observe is I have not complied my customization jar against the latest carbon kernel i.e 4.7.1. Its compiled against 4.6.0.. And I have registered my custom Userstore using BundleActivator... I can see my custom class constructor logs during startup and other methods getting  invoked.. only the doAuthenticate doesn't get  called.. any further help is highly appreciated. Regards.